# How can I modify Index security Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift, kibana, openshift-origin

I've deployed an EFK stack on Red Hat Openshift as per their docs. Here's the [github](https://github.com/openshift/origin-aggregated-logging).

When I create new indices from outside the openshift cluster (I.E. not autocreated with a project) I'm able to view them in kibana as a cluster admin, but other users cannot.

How do I change permissions on these additional indices so that other users can view the logs there?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the users a view access in the namespace/project where the EFK is deployed.

`oc adm policy add-role-to-user view <user> -n <project>`

Comment: They have admin access to the project - index still does not show up.